# Changing a object location with CSS

Tags: css, forms, css-position

I am trying to use a password only login system which can be viewed at this url: http://tinyurl.com/qamzr9k

I grabbed and used CSS (from a CSS site) to style and position the login box and submit button.

However, there is a big grey ugly bar that is accross the screen, just about the login box.

I would like to move that ugly header box from there since I want to place other content above the login form.

But in despite of my efforts and messy changes I have made to the CSS code, the box will not move.

I also notice that a required display message field for errors is fit within that box. (please type anything in the password field and submit to see what I am talking about).
So, I am wondering if moving the grey box might mean moving that required message display.

The entire CSS etc is too long to list here. So please visit: http://tinyurl.com/qamzr9k  and then view the source code.

I think the grey box is identified with the following piece of snippet in the body of the page (I renamed the div);

```
<div class="topbar" style="width:500px; top: 209px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center"></div>
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. Can you please say where I can position the form more closer to the top? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you restructure your html to the following.. by having the form inside of the coming-soon div it should wrap up all of the form inside that div... including the top bar.

```
<div class="coming-soon">
  <form method="post">
    <span>Incorrect code.</span>
    <input type="password" name="access_password"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

I can't see the use of

```
<div class="topbar" ...
```

So would maybe remove that

You can then style the form how you require keeping it relative to your coming soon div and having the error message always attached in the form

Comment: Hey Pal. This worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. However, if you look at the code, can you say exactly where I can make changes to its location from the top? I don't want to do anything to mess the code up again.

Comment: now you can manage it through the css in the coming-soon class. Remove the absolute positioning (unless you do need to keep it).. if so just edit the 'top' to where you want it
.coming-soon {
height: 105px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -156px;
margin-top: 95px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
}

Comment: Thanks again. I did just that and its work. I tried adding an image which is not showing up above the login field. I am not sure if it is an issue with the CSS. Also the login window is no longer showing up on internet explorer. Sorry to be bothering you again with this. any ideas? http://tinyurl.com/qamzr9k

Comment: no probs... the image issue is in your css you have the property opacity: 0; in the img {} tag for css. opacity goes from 0-1 in decimal increments (0 being invisible).. the form appears fine for me in ie11 so unsuer what your issue is there... I suggest having a read through css on w3 school site and also checking out http://css-tricks.com/.. it could be a lot of help... just on another note, you have * { border-box: box-sizing }... these two are the other way around, box-sizing is the attribute and border-box is the value :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
form {
animation: 1.5s ease 0s normal none 1 appear;
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
border-radius: 6px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset, 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
padding: 10px;
position: relative;
top: -54px;
}
```

As you can see here i have added `top`,so that initially your page will hide the error box.

Comment: Thanks. However, I decided to try the suggestion given by another user. But thanks for your generosity and willingness to help.